# How To Calculate and Print CDF and Lower Bound CDF value for some t (time) with Minitab (without examining the plot)

Tags: confidence-interval, cumulative-distribution-function, minitab, engineering-statistics

I'm a reliability engineer. Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) in statistics stands for the unreliability (probability of failure at a time value) of the item being tested. Unreliability is very important for reliability discipline.

Using one,sided confidence interval is also very important to minimize the risks. (stands for cost risks for me generally)

I couldn't find on web so my question is:

**How To Manually Calculate and Print CDF and Lower Bound CDF value for some t (time) with Minitab (without examining  the plot). (in the session window for example)**

in the figures below, I have 5 data seems to distribute exponential.

in figure 1, the first blue dot at lowest side, unreliability is %26.5625 @ 257 hours

in figure 2, I targeted with my pointer the confidence intersection of 257hours and got the mini window with data. As you see, for example, cdf is 0.3 @286 hours and its lower bound is 165hours.

**Actually minitab calculates everything I need and plot it.** What I only need is ask to minitab to give me the CDF and lower bound value for a specific time. Then, I can use that values in my further analysis and reports.

I think there should be some place but I couldn't find it. minitab version is 16.

I don't have any other related software. Can you please help me.

best regards

[image] 
[image]